# Убрать переносы строки

Tags: php, wordpress

Правлю тему `Wordpress` под себя.  Мешает перенос строки. Не могу его словить.

Вот кусок из `content.php`:

```
<?php twentytwelve_entry_meta(); ?>
        <?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?>
            <div class="comments-link">
                <?php comments_popup_link( '<span class="leave-reply">' . __( 'Leave a reply', 'twentytwelve' ) . '</span>', __( '1 Reply', 'twentytwelve' ), __( '% Replies', 'twentytwelve' ) ); ?>
            </div><!-- .comments-link -->
        <?php endif; // comments_open() ?>
```

Вот кусок из `functions.php`:

```
function twentytwelve_entry_meta() {
// Translators: used between list items, there is a space after the comma.
$categories_list = get_the_category_list( __( ', ', 'twentytwelve' ) );

// Translators: used between list items, there is a space after the comma.
$tag_list = get_the_tag_list( '', __( ', ', 'twentytwelve' ) );

$date = sprintf( '<a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="bookmark"><time class="entry-date" datetime="%3$s">%4$s</time></a>',
    esc_url( get_permalink() ),
    esc_attr( get_the_time() ),
    esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
    esc_html( get_the_date() )
);

$author = sprintf( '<span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="author">%3$s</a></span>',
    esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ),
    esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'View all posts by %s', 'twentytwelve' ), get_the_author() ) ),
    get_the_author()
);

// Translators: 1 is category, 2 is tag, 3 is the date and 4 is the author's name.
if ( $tag_list ) {
    $utility_text = __( ' %3$s | %1$s | Теги: %2$s | ' , 'twentytwelve' );
} elseif ( $categories_list ) {
    $utility_text = __( '%3$s | %1$s | %3$s', 'twentytwelve' );
} else {
    $utility_text = __( '%3$s', 'twentytwelve' );
}

printf(
    $utility_text,
    $categories_list,
    $tag_list,
    $date,
    $author
);
 }
 endif;
```

Вот скриншот. Фраза про комментарии должна быть на той же строке, что и теги.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не могли бы вы привести код, где есть этот лишний перенос?

Comment: Добавил скриншот :) А сам код уже был в вопросе.